# Adding PartialView in layout

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have created _LoginPartial and used it in default _Layout, it's working properly but when I created another _AdminLayout, there I got the issue.

I have already added top on the page

```
@using System.Web.Mvc
@using System.Web.Mvc.Html
```

I am not able to add my _LoginPartial  in _AdminLayout and getting the following error

> "System.Web.WebPages.Html.HtmlHelper' does not contain a definition
>   for 'Partial' and the best extension method overload
>   'System.Web.Mvc.Html.PartialExtensions.Partial(System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper,
>   string)' has some invalid arguments "

My code is

```
 @using System.Web.Mvc
 @using System.Web.Mvc.Html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="en">
  <head>
   @*<title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
   <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Site.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.4.4.min.js")"
 type="text/javascript"></script>*@
<style type="text/css">
    /*Initialize*/ul#menu, ul#menu ul.sub-menu
    {
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
    }
    ul#menu li, ul#menu ul.sub-menu li
    {
        list-style-type: none;
        display: inline-block;
    }
    /*Link
     Appearance*/ul#menu li a, ul#menu li ul.sub-menu li a
    {
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #fff;
        background: #666;
        padding: 5px;
        display: inline-block;
    }
    /*Make the
     parent of sub-menu relative*/ul#menu li
    {
        position: relative;
    }
    /*sub menu*/ul#menu li ul.sub-menu
    {
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        top: 30px;
        left: 0;
        width: 100px;
    }
    ul#menu li:hover ul.sub-menu
    {
        display: block;
    }
    </style>
   </head>
 <body>
  <div>

    <table border="1" width="100%" style="background-color: Lime; margin-top: 30px">
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.Partial("_LoginPartial")
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <ul id="menu">

                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Manage Product</a>
                        <ul class="sub-menu">

                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Manage Order</a>
                        <ul class="sub-menu">

                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Manege user</a>
                        <ul class="sub-menu">

                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Set NewProduct</a>
                        <ul class="sub-menu">

                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Set Home Category</a>
                        <ul class="sub-menu">

                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Category Wise product</a>
                        <ul class="sub-menu">

                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Feature product</a>
                        <ul class="sub-menu">

                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                @RenderBody()
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: What is the code you are using to render the partial? In which folders are your partial views located?

Comment: Hi Rowan , i am using the   @Html.Partial("_LoginPartial")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have copy web.config file where is my another layout and its work for me . 
I don't know this is good way or not but my issue is resolved

Thanks for your comments and response

Thanks 
Anil

Answer (score 1):

the main problem of this is the missing of namespace in your web.config ... make sure you have this in the namespaces section of the web.config or even you could include it inside your layout file itself `@using System.Web.Mvc.Html;`

```
<add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html"/>
```

sometimes it is caused also by using a partial view in a view that is having any defined model especially if you are passing model object of anonymous object.

if you want to pass a custom params instead of model object below is an example:

```
@Html.Partial("_PartialView", null, new ViewDataDictionary(new { showEmployeeBanner = "true", }))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your adminPartial is has some another folder , So you get this error

. Please set the correct URL in your partial page,Wherever call that.

```
/Shared/adminPartial.cshtml
```

Answer (score 0):

use @Html.Partial("../Views/YourFolder/_LoginPartial") and try